# Multiple Counts Over Multiple Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am essentially doing the following query (edited):

```
Select count(orders)
From Orders_Table
Where Order_Open_Date<=##/##/####
and Order_Close_Date>=##/##/####
```

Where the ##/##/##### is the same date. So in essence the number of 'open' orders for any given day. However I am wanting this same count for every single day for a year and don't want to write a separate query for each day for the whole year.  I'm sorry this is probably really simple but I am new to SQL and I guess I don't know how to search for an answer to this question since my searches have come up with nothing.  Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL flavor)? What is the data type of `Order_Date`? Are you familiar with `GROUP BY`? Do you have to have *zero* count for days that you have no records for?

Comment: I use Oracle.  I am familiar with Group By and the answers I've received I see revolve around using that-unfortunately I realized that in phrasing my question this will be problematic since I need the number of 'open' orders on a given day since the order isn't usually a one-day deal.  So really my query is more like: Select count (orders) from Order_table where Order_Open_Date<=##/##/#### and Order_Close_Date>=##/##/#### so I think that it won't work to have the group by since I don't want orders grouped by either the close date or the open date if that makes sense.

Comment: Please post an updated query into your post (edit it in).  If you can't edit your own post, let me know and I'll do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not

```
select Order_Date, count(orders) from Orders_Table group by Order_Date
```

and for last year

```
select Order_Date, count(orders) from Orders_Table where Order_Date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) group by Order_Date;
```

Comment: That will not limit it to 1 year, as OP indicated.

Comment: Thanks kitty, sorry one follow up question as I'm realizing that I didn't quite phrase this right.  What if my query is more like this:  Select count(orders) from order_table where Order_Open_Date<=DATE and Order_Close_Date>=DATE.  In essence this is measuring the 'open' orders on a given day and so I can't group by the open or close date if that makes sense.  Can I create a new date variable to group by?  Not sure how I'd do that.

Comment: you can also group by both - ...GROUP BY Order_Close_Date, Order_Open_Date; - is that what you want? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, Order_Date, 110), count(orders)
    FROM Orders_Table
    WHERE Order_Date = BETWEEN @A AND @B
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, Order_Date, 110)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have *every* day of the year, including those with no orders, you will need to generate a temporary table or similar containing every date in the range and left/right join it to the Orders_Table data. This depends upon which RDBMS you're using. In SQL Server I have done this using a user defined function which returns a table variable.